# Fail to install gmp-mpfr-sys crate through cargo on mac OS

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I had a hard time to install gmp-mpfr-sys. I am using Catalina 10.15.7. Is this Rust crate installable on mac at all?

It looks like some test-suits of gmp caused segmentation fault.

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
gmp-mpfr-sys = "1.4"
```

```
  libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for kabylake-apple-darwin19.6.0
  libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
  libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for kabylake-apple-darwin19.6.0
  libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
  libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for kabylake-apple-darwin19.6.0
  libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
  libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for kabylake-apple-darwin19.6.0
  libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
  ../../../gmp-src/test-driver: line 107: 81118 Segmentation fault: 11  "$@" > $log_file 2>&1
  make[5]: *** [test-suite.log] Error 1
  make[4]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 2
  make[3]: *** [check-am] Error 2
  make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
  make: *** [check] Error 2
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Program failed with code 2: "make" "-j" "16" "check"', ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/gmp-mpfr-sys-1.4.9/build.rs:1300:13
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```